# Activerecord query with relation

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a simple shopping cart app.

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items
  has_one :order
end   

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :product
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

The line_item model has a string column named "delivery" and the product model has a string column named "name".

I need to make a query that checks if there is a LineItem, where delivery == "foo" and the associated Product name == "bar"

The query should return a boolean value.
In one of my views I need to make a query that tells me if there is a line_item where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess something like this would do the trick:

```
LineItem.joins(:product).where(products: {name: 'bar'}).where(delivery: 'foo').exists?
```

Comment: I get this error: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: product.name: Of course the column exists... Product.last.name
  Product Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products"   ORDER BY "products"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> "Jacket"

Comment: Woops, the product table name must be in plural. `.where(products: {name: 'bar'})`  #edited

Comment: Just FYI: A single `where` would be preferable: `{delivery: 'foo', "products.name" => 'bar'}` or `{delivery: 'foo', {products: {name: 'bar'}}`